# How to exclude sub type in the hybris flexible search

Tags: data-modeling, sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

In hybris, I have Created **ArchivalOrderModel** extends **orderModel**

Moved Data from OrderModel To ArchivalOrderModel. (Deleted Record from OrderModel)

When I fired query

```
select {pk} from {order}
```

In result Im getting Records of ArchivalOrderModel too.

Is there any way to restrict with help of data Modeling definition or Any other suggestion for archival

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When we search any type, by default its subtypes will also be retrieved in the result.

If you want to exclude the subtype, you must use the exclamation mark (!) while specifying the type in the query like this.

```
Select * from {Order!}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Do we have any option with restriction in data modeling

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question? when you say "restriction in data modeling", what you want to achieve?

Comment: If you want to separate the ArchivalOrder instances into another table, then you would need to create a new type inheriting from AbstractOrder rather than from Order.  Then you would need to define a deployment table for that new type. Note: you also then need to define a new child type of AbstractOrderEntry (plus deployment table).